# UDS-R 2012 - AskUbuntu UDS event

Tags: discussion, uds

[image]

This year Ubuntu Development Summit has a session specifically to discuss AskUbuntu integration into all things related to Ubuntu Development.

You are cordially invited to attend!

*how to*

Using your launchpad account - sign up to join the Etherpad team

- https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad

Then on November 1st 16:15 - 17:00 Central European Time sign-in to the event.

- http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-r/meeting/21179/community-r-askubuntu/

```
Copenhagan                         Thursday, 1 November 2012, 16:00:00 CET UTC+1 hour  
United Kingdom - England           Thursday, 1 November 2012, 15:00:00 GMT UTC         
New York (U.S.A. - New York)       Thursday, 1 November 2012, 11:00:00 EDT UTC-4 hours 
Los Angeles (U.S.A. - California)  Thursday, 1 November 2012, 08:00:00 PDT UTC-7 hours 
Corresponding UTC (GMT)            Thursday, 1 November 2012, 15:00:00
```

EDIT:

Well things change so quickly!

The session timings were changed rapidly and brought forward.

- http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-r/meeting/21178/appdev-r-askubuntu-app-developer-site-plugin/